# Google Charts Tools - Como mudar cores dos rótulos

Tags: google-charts

Montei um gráfico de linhas usando Google Chart Tools. Porém não consigo mudar as cores dos rótulos. Vejam esse gráfico:

http://assets.chris-saylor.com/img/g_chart_example1.png

Como eu mudaria as cores daqueles valores S1, S2, S3 (abaixo do gráfico) e as escalas numéricas do lado esquerdo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Já que você postou apenas uma imagem do gráfico estarei levando em consideração o código de exemplo do [Google Charts Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground) tendo apenas os valores do eixo horizontal similares ao proposto (S1, S2...).

Para atingir aquilo que deseja você deve configurar a propriedade **textStyle** do **vAxis** e o **hAxis**. De acordo com [a documentação](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) temos algo assim:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'Piston 1', 'Piston 2'],
    ['S1',   1,       1],
    ['S2',   2,       0.5],
    ['S3',   4,       1],
    ['S4',   8,       0.5],
    ['S5',   7,       1],
    ['S6',   7,       0.5],
    ['S7',   8,       1],
    ['S8',   4,       0.5],
    ['S9',   2,       1],
    ['S10',   3.5,     0.5],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.

  new google.visualization.LineChart(

      document.getElementById('visualization'))
              .draw(
                  data,
                  {
                      width: 500, height: 400,
                      hAxis: {textStyle: { color: 'red'}},
                      vAxis: {textStyle: { color: 'blue'}}

                  }
  );
}
```

​Esse exemplo fará os números verticais ficarem azuis e os horizontais, vermelhos.

> Por algum motivo que desconheço, pelo menos no Playground os rótulos horizontais não estão alinhados.

Comment: Eu já havia achado exemplos desse tipo no google, porém no exemplo que achei, a palavra TextStyle estava escrito com T maiúsculo e por isso não funcionava. Mas agora problema resolvido. Grato.

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar. Não se esqueça de ao menos marcar a resposta como resolvida. Sua dúvida hoje pode ser a de outra pessoa amanhã. ;)